# unable to connect hazzelcast IMDG locally from .net hazelcast client

Tags: hazelcast

I have downloaded the hazelcast locally. but when i am trying to connect it from .net client it does not get connected.
below exception is shown in console of Hazecast.

om.hazelcast.internal.nio.tcp.TcpIpConnection
WARNING: [10.253.200.102]:5701 [dev] [4.0.1] Connection[id=7, /10.253.200.102:5701->/10.253.200.102:56020, qualifier=null, endpoint=null, alive=false, connectionType=NONE] closed. Reason: Exception in Connection[id=7, /10.253.200.102:5701->/10.253.200.102:56020, qualifier=null, endpoint=null, alive=true, connectionType=NONE], thread=hz.epic_northcutt.IO.thread-in-0
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unknown protocol: CB2
at com.hazelcast.internal.nio.tcp.UnifiedProtocolDecoder.onRead(UnifiedProtocolDecoder.java:116)
at com.hazelcast.internal.networking.nio.NioInboundPipeline.process(NioInboundPipeline.java:137)
at com.hazelcast.internal.networking.nio.NioThread.processSelectionKey(NioThread.java:382)
at com.hazelcast.internal.networking.nio.NioThread.processSelectionKeys(NioThread.java:367)
at com.hazelcast.internal.networking.nio.NioThread.selectLoop(NioThread.java:293)
at com.hazelcast.internal.networking.nio.NioThread.run(NioThread.java:248)

enter image description here

```
**Default Hazelcast Config file:**      

<hazelcast xmlns="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config
           http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config/hazelcast-config-4.0.xsd">

    <cluster-name>dev</cluster-name>

    <network>
        <port auto-increment="true" port-count="100">5701</port>
        <outbound-ports>
            <!--
            Allowed port range when connecting to other nodes.
            0 or * means use system provided port.
            -->
            <ports>0</ports>
        </outbound-ports>
        <join>
            <multicast enabled="true">
                <multicast-group>224.2.2.3</multicast-group>
                <multicast-port>54327</multicast-port>
            </multicast>
            <tcp-ip enabled="false">
                <interface>127.0.0.1</interface>
                <member-list>
                    <member>127.0.0.1</member>
                </member-list>
            </tcp-ip>
            <aws enabled="false">
                <access-key>my-access-key</access-key>
                <secret-key>my-secret-key</secret-key>
                <!--optional, default is us-east-1 -->
                <region>us-west-1</region>
                <!--optional, default is ec2.amazonaws.com. If set, region shouldn't be set as it will override this property -->
                <host-header>ec2.amazonaws.com</host-header>
                <!-- optional, only instances belonging to this group will be discovered, default will try all running instances -->
                <security-group-name>hazelcast-sg</security-group-name>
                <tag-key>type</tag-key>
                <tag-value>hz-nodes</tag-value>
            </aws>
            <gcp enabled="false">
                <zones>us-east1-b,us-east1-c</zones>
            </gcp>
            <azure enabled="false">
                <client-id>CLIENT_ID</client-id>
                <client-secret>CLIENT_SECRET</client-secret>
                <tenant-id>TENANT_ID</tenant-id>
                <subscription-id>SUB_ID</subscription-id>
                <cluster-id>HZLCAST001</cluster-id>
                <group-name>RESOURCE-GROUP-NAME</group-name>
            </azure>
            <kubernetes enabled="false">
                <namespace>MY-KUBERNETES-NAMESPACE</namespace>
                <service-name>MY-SERVICE-NAME</service-name>
                <service-label-name>MY-SERVICE-LABEL-NAME</service-label-name>
                <service-label-value>MY-SERVICE-LABEL-VALUE</service-label-value>
            </kubernetes>
            <eureka enabled="false">
                <self-registration>true</self-registration>
                <namespace>hazelcast</namespace>
            </eureka>
            <discovery-strategies>
            </discovery-strategies>
        </join>
        <interfaces enabled="false">
            <interface>10.10.1.*</interface>
        </interfaces>
        <ssl enabled="false"/>
        <socket-interceptor enabled="false"/>
        <symmetric-encryption enabled="false">
            <!--
               encryption algorithm such as
               DES/ECB/PKCS5Padding,
               PBEWithMD5AndDES,
               AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding,
               Blowfish,
               DESede
            -->
            <algorithm>PBEWithMD5AndDES</algorithm>
            <!-- salt value to use when generating the secret key -->
            <salt>thesalt</salt>
            <!-- pass phrase to use when generating the secret key -->
            <password>thepass</password>
            <!-- iteration count to use when generating the secret key -->
            <iteration-count>19</iteration-count>
        </symmetric-encryption>
        <failure-detector>
            <icmp enabled="false"/>
        </failure-detector>
    </network>
    <partition-group enabled="false"/>
    <executor-service name="default">
        <pool-size>16</pool-size>
        <!--Queue capacity. 0 means Integer.MAX_VALUE.-->
        <queue-capacity>0</queue-capacity>
    </executor-service>
    <security>
        <client-block-unmapped-actions>true</client-block-unmapped-actions>
    </security>
    <queue name="default">
        <!--
            Maximum size of the queue. When a JVM's local queue size reaches the maximum,
            all put/offer operations will get blocked until the queue size
            of the JVM goes down below the maximum.
            Any integer between 0 and Integer.MAX_VALUE. 0 means
            Integer.MAX_VALUE. Default is 0.
        -->
        <max-size>0</max-size>
        <!--
            Number of backups. If 1 is set as the backup-count for example,
            then all entries of the map will be copied to another JVM for
            fail-safety. 0 means no backup.
        -->
        <backup-count>1</backup-count>

        <!--
            Number of async backups. 0 means no backup.
        -->
        <async-backup-count>0</async-backup-count>

        <empty-queue-ttl>-1</empty-queue-ttl>

        <merge-policy batch-size="100">com.hazelcast.spi.merge.PutIfAbsentMergePolicy</merge-policy>
    </queue>
    <map name="default">
        <!--
           Data type that will be used for storing recordMap.
           Possible values:
           BINARY (default): keys and values will be stored as binary data
           OBJECT : values will be stored in their object forms
           NATIVE : values will be stored in non-heap region of JVM
        -->
        <in-memory-format>BINARY</in-memory-format>

        <!--
            Metadata creation policy for this map. Hazelcast may process objects of supported types ahead of time to
            create additional metadata about them. This metadata then is used to make querying and indexing faster.
            Metadata creation may decrease put throughput.
            Valid values are:
            CREATE_ON_UPDATE (default): Objects of supported types are pre-processed when they are created and updated.
            OFF: No metadata is created.
        -->
        <metadata-policy>CREATE_ON_UPDATE</metadata-policy>

        <!--
            Number of backups. If 1 is set as the backup-count for example,
            then all entries of the map will be copied to another JVM for
            fail-safety. 0 means no backup.
        -->
        <backup-count>1</backup-count>
        <!--
            Number of async backups. 0 means no backup.
        -->
        <async-backup-count>0</async-backup-count>
        <!--
            Maximum number of seconds for each entry to stay in the map. Entries that are
            older than <time-to-live-seconds> and not updated for <time-to-live-seconds>
            will get automatically evicted from the map.
            Any integer between 0 and Integer.MAX_VALUE. 0 means infinite. Default is 0
        -->
        <time-to-live-seconds>0</time-to-live-seconds>
        <!--
            Maximum number of seconds for each entry to stay idle in the map. Entries that are
            idle(not touched) for more than <max-idle-seconds> will get
            automatically evicted from the map. Entry is touched if get, put or containsKey is called.
            Any integer between 0 and Integer.MAX_VALUE. 0 means infinite. Default is 0.
        -->
        <max-idle-seconds>0</max-idle-seconds>

        <eviction eviction-policy="NONE" max-size-policy="PER_NODE" size="0"/>
        <!--
            While recovering from split-brain (network partitioning),
            map entries in the small cluster will merge into the bigger cluster
            based on the policy set here. When an entry merge into the
            cluster, there might an existing entry with the same key already.
            Values of these entries might be different for that same key.
            Which value should be set for the key? Conflict is resolved by
            the policy set here. Default policy is PutIfAbsentMapMergePolicy

            There are built-in merge policies such as
            com.hazelcast.spi.merge.PassThroughMergePolicy; entry will be overwritten if merging entry exists for the key.
            com.hazelcast.spi.merge.PutIfAbsentMergePolicy ; entry will be added if the merging entry doesn't exist in the cluster.
            com.hazelcast.spi.merge.HigherHitsMergePolicy ; entry with the higher hits wins.
            com.hazelcast.spi.merge.LatestUpdateMergePolicy ; entry with the latest update wins.
        -->
        <merge-policy batch-size="100">com.hazelcast.spi.merge.PutIfAbsentMergePolicy</merge-policy>

        <!--
           Control caching of de-serialized values. Caching makes query evaluation faster, but it cost memory.
           Possible Values:
                        NEVER: Never cache deserialized object
                        INDEX-ONLY: Caches values only when they are inserted into an index.
                        ALWAYS: Always cache deserialized values.
        -->
        <cache-deserialized-values>INDEX-ONLY</cache-deserialized-values>

    </map>

    <multimap name="default">
        <backup-count>1</backup-count>
        <value-collection-type>SET</value-collection-type>
        <merge-policy batch-size="100">com.hazelcast.spi.merge.PutIfAbsentMergePolicy</merge-policy>
    </multimap>

    <replicatedmap name="default">
        <in-memory-format>OBJECT</in-memory-format>
        <async-fillup>true</async-fillup>
        <statistics-enabled>true</statistics-enabled>
        <merge-policy batch-size="100">com.hazelcast.spi.merge.PutIfAbsentMergePolicy</merge-policy>
    </replicatedmap>

    <list name="default">
        <backup-count>1</backup-count>
        <merge-policy batch-size="100">com.hazelcast.spi.merge.PutIfAbsentMergePolicy</merge-policy>
    </list>

    <set name="default">
        <backup-count>1</backup-count>
        <merge-policy batch-size="100">com.hazelcast.spi.merge.PutIfAbsentMergePolicy</merge-policy>
    </set>

    <reliable-topic name="default">
        <read-batch-size>10</read-batch-size>
        <topic-overload-policy>BLOCK</topic-overload-policy>
        <statistics-enabled>true</statistics-enabled>
    </reliable-topic>

    <ringbuffer name="default">
        <capacity>10000</capacity>
        <backup-count>1</backup-count>
        <async-backup-count>0</async-backup-count>
        <time-to-live-seconds>0</time-to-live-seconds>
        <in-memory-format>BINARY</in-memory-format>
        <merge-policy batch-size="100">com.hazelcast.spi.merge.PutIfAbsentMergePolicy</merge-policy>
    </ringbuffer>

    <flake-id-generator name="default">
        <prefetch-count>100</prefetch-count>
        <prefetch-validity-millis>600000</prefetch-validity-millis>
        <epoch-start>1514764800000</epoch-start>
        <node-id-offset>0</node-id-offset>
        <bits-sequence>6</bits-sequence>
        <bits-node-id>16</bits-node-id>
        <allowed-future-millis>15000</allowed-future-millis>
        <statistics-enabled>true</statistics-enabled>
    </flake-id-generator>

    <serialization>
        <portable-version>0</portable-version>
    </serialization>

    <lite-member enabled="false"/>

    <cardinality-estimator name="default">
        <backup-count>1</backup-count>
        <async-backup-count>0</async-backup-count>
        <merge-policy batch-size="100">HyperLogLogMergePolicy</merge-policy>
    </cardinality-estimator>

    <scheduled-executor-service name="default">
        <capacity>100</capacity>
        <durability>1</durability>
        <pool-size>16</pool-size>
        <merge-policy batch-size="100">com.hazelcast.spi.merge.PutIfAbsentMergePolicy</merge-policy>
    </scheduled-executor-service>

    <crdt-replication>
        <replication-period-millis>1000</replication-period-millis>
        <max-concurrent-replication-targets>1</max-concurrent-replication-targets>
    </crdt-replication>

    <pn-counter name="default">
        <replica-count>2147483647</replica-count>
        <statistics-enabled>true</statistics-enabled>
    </pn-counter>

    <cp-subsystem>
        <cp-member-count>0</cp-member-count>
        <group-size>0</group-size>
        <session-time-to-live-seconds>300</session-time-to-live-seconds>
        <session-heartbeat-interval-seconds>5</session-heartbeat-interval-seconds>
        <missing-cp-member-auto-removal-seconds>14400</missing-cp-member-auto-removal-seconds>
        <fail-on-indeterminate-operation-state>false</fail-on-indeterminate-operation-state>
        <raft-algorithm>
            <leader-election-timeout-in-millis>2000</leader-election-timeout-in-millis>
            <leader-heartbeat-period-in-millis>5000</leader-heartbeat-period-in-millis>
            <max-missed-leader-heartbeat-count>5</max-missed-leader-heartbeat-count>
            <append-request-max-entry-count>100</append-request-max-entry-count>
            <commit-index-advance-count-to-snapshot>10000</commit-index-advance-count-to-snapshot>
            <uncommitted-entry-count-to-reject-new-appends>100</uncommitted-entry-count-to-reject-new-appends>
            <append-request-backoff-timeout-in-millis>100</append-request-backoff-timeout-in-millis>
        </raft-algorithm>
    </cp-subsystem>

    <metrics enabled="true">
        <management-center enabled="true">
            <retention-seconds>5</retention-seconds>
        </management-center>
        <jmx enabled="true"/>
        <collection-frequency-seconds>5</collection-frequency-seconds>
    </metrics>
</hazelcast>


**Client Code:** 

using Hazelcast.Client;
using Hazelcast.Config;
using Hazelcast.Core;
using System;

namespace HazelCastClientApp1
{
    public class HazelcastClientFactory
    {
        static IHazelcastInstance client;

        public static IHazelcastInstance GetClient()
        {
            if (client == null)
            {
                InitializeClient();
            }

            return client;
        }   


        private static void InitializeClient()
        {
            var cfg = new ClientConfig();
            var hazelcastUrl = "127.0.0.1:5701";
            cfg.GetNetworkConfig().AddAddress(hazelcastUrl);
            client = HazelcastClient.NewHazelcastClient(cfg);
            Console.WriteLine("Local address : {0}", client.GetLocalEndpoint().GetSocketAddress());
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the version of your client?

Answer (score 0):

The `[4.0.1]` and `Unknown protocol: CB2` mentions in the error messages indicate that you are trying to connect a v3 client to a v4 server. The v3 client does not support v4 servers. Please ensure that you are using compatible client and server.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, it was my mistake